# can I use blend or tint on numerous video each other in processing?

Tags: video, processing, overlay, blend, tint

I want to make overlay two videos. I want to make the water caustic video above the video of swimming fishes. and I did. But when I get tint on the water caustic video and make that 50% transparency. And then the fishes video also becomes 50% transparency. I just want to make 50% transparency "the water caustic video" only. and the below video(fish video) stay 100% opacity.

Comment: Welcome! I strongly suggest that you "take the tour" you declined, or at the very least read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You have to help us help you if you want to raise your chances of someone taking time to read and reflect on your question. Right now, I suggest that you post a [Minimal, reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question so we can see what you're doing, then someone will probably spot where's the problem.

Comment: Share your code, please